# Is using reflection to find type of abstract property a code smell?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

So say I have three classes: A, B, and C. A is abstract, B and C inherit from A.

I have created a list of A classes. In a function, I need to know the type of the class I have: A, B, or C. Do I use reflection to get the name? Assign it a type variable and check that? Or am I using abstraction fundamentally wrong?

```
public abstract class A
{
    public string Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        this.Type = "B";
        Console.WriteLine("I am of type B!");
    }
}
public class C : A
{
    public C()
    {
        this.Type = "C";
        Console.WriteLine("I am of type C!");
    }
}

List<A> listOfStuff = new List<A>();
void doSomething()
{
    listOfStuff.Add(new A());
    listOfStuff.Add(new B());
    listOfStuff.Add(new C());

    foreach (A item in listOfStuff)
    {
        doOperation(item);
    }
}
void doOperation(A thing1)
{
    //Is this bad practice?
    if (thing1.GetType().Name == "B")
    {
        //Do code
    }
    //Or what about this?
    if (thing1.Type == "B")
    {
        //Do code
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of those checks in `doOperation` will give you trouble as the list of possible types to handle there will grow. What are you trying to do? Why don't you just use an interface that related types can implement?

Comment: Looks like you're just looking for *virtual methods* here.

Comment: Question might be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Sam when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @xxbbcc The reason I am asking this is because I have a hitbox detection algorithm for different hitboxes. Square-Circle, Circle-Circle, and Square-Square. All of these objects (Circle, Square) inherit from a base hitbox class. I then iterate through all hitboxes and check to see if they intersect, to do that I must choose the appropriate algorithm which I can only get from knowing the type of the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps a violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), the L in [SOLID.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) If a bunch of "A"s are in a list, it should be possible to operate on them without "knowing" their subtype. If they're all going to be cast as A but then you have to reinspect them to determine their actual type and handle them differently then it defeats the purpose of being able to refer to them by their base type.

If the different types can all expose the same properties (describing area, dimensions, etc.) then an interface might be better than an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

No need to work that hard.  Just use [is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

```
public abstract class A
{
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am of type B!");
    }
}
public class C : A
{
    public C()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am of type C!");
    }
}

static List<A> listOfStuff = new List<A>();
public static void doSomething()
{
    listOfStuff.Add(new B());
    listOfStuff.Add(new C());

    foreach (A item in listOfStuff)
    {
        doOperation(item);
    }
}
static void doOperation(A thing1)
{
    if (thing1 is B)
    {
        //Do code for B
    }

    if (thing1 is C)
    {
        //Do code for C
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rob Deary has already shown you how to avoid doing it but he didn't specifically answer your question.

I would say that "code smell" is far too mild a term for what you wrote in your OP.  The only good case I can see for using reflection to find an object's type is some sort of logging or reporting function.  (Something that's going to print "I got a **B**".)  It would be possibly tolerable if it was needed to work around a bug in code you couldn't fix.  Beyond that don't do it.